# TypeError: offer() missing 1 positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, aiohttp

**Edit**: after @Ajax1234 answer

Now I'm getting internal server error in console and in my app.py env I get

> TypeError: offer() missing 1 positional argument: 'request'

I know that there is a lot of similar questions but they ain't for me so to long story short I wrote quick app app flask with webRTC that works perfectly but when I'm trying to implement my solution to existing project my code doesn't work. I have no previous experience with flask I was just thrown there to do something

This works:

```py
async def javascript(request):
    content = open(os.path.join(ROOT, "streaming.js"), "r").read()
    return web.Response(content_type="application/javascript", text=content)

async def offer(request):
    params = await request.json()
    offer = RTCSessionDescription(sdp=params["sdp"], type=params["type"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get("/", index)
    app.router.add_get("/streaming.js", javascript)
    app.router.add_post("/offer", offer)
    web.run_app(app)
```

with this js snippet

```js
 var offer = pc.localDescription;
        return fetch('/offer', {
            body: JSON.stringify({
                sdp: offer.sdp,
                type: offer.type,
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST'
        });
```

but when I'm implementing this code to work with current app and adding `app.route("/offer/something)` it just doesn't work and being honest I don't know why because I don't know flask

```py
@app.route('/streaming.js/<request>', methods=['GET'])
async def javascript(request):
    content = open(os.path.join(ROOT, "streaming.js"), "r").read()
    print(content)
    return web.Response(content_type="application/javascript", text=content)

@app.route('/offer/<request>', methods=['POST'])
async def offer(request):
    params = await request.json()
    offer = RTCSessionDescription(sdp=params["sdp"], type=params["type"])
```

My guess it doesn't work because of the structure my app has everything in the same folder like

- app.py
- streaming.js
- index.html

but this app that I'm implementing has static template folders

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `<request>` component of the routes in your Flask app. Your `fetch` snippet is sending data attached to the request that Flask can read via the `flask.request` object:

```
@app.route('/streaming.js', methods=['GET'])
async def javascript():
   content = open(os.path.join(ROOT, "streaming.js"), "r").read()
   print(content)
   return web.Response(content_type="application/javascript", text=content)

@app.route('/offer', methods=['POST'])
async def offer():
   #request.json retrieves the data attached to the post request
   params = await request.json()
   offer = RTCSessionDescription(sdp=params["sdp"], type=params["type"])
   #do something with offer
```

Comment: I will try that and get back to you

Comment: ok, that works but now im getting internal server error in console and in my app.py env i get TypeError: offer() missing 1 positional argument: 'request'

Comment: @newDev2000 Are you attempting to access `/offer` either by navigating to that route yourself or by sending a `GET` request to it? Also, are you still using your `fetch('/offer', {})` call?

Comment: yeah I'm still using fetch for it I've changed nothing in my JS and Im sending GET request to it

Comment: @newDev2000 `/offer` only accepts a `POST` request (`methods=['POST']`). If you need to send a `GET` request to `/offer`, you can either update the `methods` list (`methods=['POST', 'GET']`) or change the request type in `fetch`

Comment: wow nah I've blacked out for a second there im using POST as you can see in my js code snippet

Comment: and im getting popup saying unexpected token < in JSON at 0